# Google App Script - Date as String Manipulation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking for a Google App Script function, which will take the following text

```
Sat May 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
```

and return

```
Sat May 12 2012
```

Is it just like javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if

```
Sat May 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
```

is a string, you can just use a string function:

```
var myDateString = "Sat May 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)";
var shorterDateStrng = myDateString.slice(0,myDateString.indexOf(":")-2);
//If this is in .gs code
Logger.log('shorterDateStrng: ' + shorterDateStrng );
```

Apps Script uses JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Best if you use the built-in utilities, which can cope with the time zone properly, rather than using string manipulation. If the date is available as a Date object (e.g. read from Google Spreadsheet), you can just pass it to `Utilities.formattedDate()`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var myDateString = "Sat May 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)"; // Want Sat May 12 2012
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(myDateString),
                                           "GMT+1000", "EEE MMM dd yyyy");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
}
```

Logging Output:

```
[14-07-11 22:32:02:438 EST] Sat May 12 2012
```

Note that the given time is GMT+10, while my script is running in GMT-5 "EST".